# Print All those numbers from a given list which contain 1,2,3 not necessarily in sequence

Tags: algorithm, numbers, digit

Print All those numbers from a given list which contain digits 1,2,3 not necessarily in sequence.

The numbers in output should be in sorted order.

Like 876321,3245,123 then output should be:

123,876321

Comment: It is sad that you have not shown own attempts to solve this problem

Comment: `output should be in sorted order` ascending(?) *lexical* or *numeric* order? What about negative numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Do a regex match using a regex with some positive lookaheads to ensure 1 2 and 3 are there. Here's an example that works with your test cases. https://regex101.com/r/y052Pi/1/

```
(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)[0-9]*
```

Put your matches into a sortable or sorted collection.

Here's a runnable js implementation.

```js
 var testValues = [876321,3245,123],
     results = [];
     
testValues.forEach( function( element ) {
  if( /^(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)[0-9]*/.test( '' + element) ) {
    results.push(element);
  }
});

results = results.sort( (a, b) => a - b );

console.log( results );
```